# Phonegap and Cordova version

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, statusbar, phonegap

I'm using phonegap and most things seem to be working ok but I wanted to change status bar colour to fit with my theme. There is a plugin which I have followed instructions to use but without success. It does say in docs that I need Cordova 5+ but I don't know how this version relates to phonegap version or where to find out which version of Cordova phone gap is employing. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**If you use phonegap** and not phonegap build you have to run this into cmd on you'r working directory :

```
cordova platform version android
```

or

```
phonegap cordova platform version android
```

### Otherwise if you use phonegap build you can find the version here :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just do `cordova -v` in cmd to get your current cordova version.

Additionally, if you can to check platform version, its `cordova platform ls` and for plugins its `cordova plugin ls`